# Upgrades: Should I stay on the Ubuntu Treadmill?

Tags: upgrade, gparted

OK, so I am a deadbeat. I just upgraded Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. (I suspect now to have LTS I cannot have installed any packages from outside the core supported in LTS). I did this only last week, the upgrade was done only after I used Partition Magic to rob space from an unused extended partition and I had to erase swap partitions to be able to resize the extended partition because it was busy, neither qparted or Partition Magic tell you that they found swap and are using it. They complain if you want to use that partition, and they should. The upgrade took a couple of hours and added more than a gig of usage on the root. So just today I get a notice from Update Manager that my install has fallen out of support. OK, I need to upgrade my install again this time to 12.04 and possibly on to 12.10. So why am I doing this? I thought that Connonical was going to lessen this rat race, or is it a race condition? I think that it is a bad idea to be on a bleeding edge anyway preferring to be down rev a couple. I vote for a longer support cycle and consider this cause to replace ubuntu with another linux.

Answer (score 2):

Every long term support release is supported for five years, while the in-between releases are each supported for two years. If you are interested in a longer support cycle, Ubuntu 12.04 is the way to go, and you could also have stuck with Ubuntu 10.04 for a while longer. The next LTS release will be Ubuntu 14.04, and when that comes out you will be able to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 in one step, but you don't *need* to do that until April 2017.